# How to use aioresponses for mocking ClientSession without passing in the session as parameter

Tags: python, mocking, aiohttp

I tried using [aioresponses](https://pypi.org/project/aioresponses/) to mock ClientSession POST request. But i get *cannot connect to host sever*. I am just using aiohttp client and not server. Also i do not want to pass in the fake session as a parameter to the test function. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 6):

I think you should use `aioresponses` to mock the whole url of the endpoint of the remote host.

Let's suppose, that we are going to mock the external service like Telegram Bot API server. We want to test method `sendMessage` of our client library `ClientTgBot` which sends POST request.

Out project structure is like:

```
/app
 - __init__.py
 - client_tgbot.py
/tests/
 - __init_.py
 - conftest.py
 - test_client_tgbot_unit.py
```

Let's assume that our `app/client_tgbot.py` contains some logic, for example ClientTgBot with the method to test:

```
# app/client_tgbot.py
from aiohttp import ClientSession

class ClientTgBot:
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token

    async def sendMessage(self, chat_id, text):
        """
        We want to test this method
        without sending POST request to the host https://api.telegram.org
        """
        url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + self.token + '/sendMessage'
        async with ClientSession() as c:
            response = await c.post(url, json={'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': text})
            return response
```

Our fixtures:

```
# tests/conftest.py
import pytest
from aioresponses import aioresponses
from app.client_tgbot import ClientTgBot

@pytest.fixture
def mock_aioresponse():
    with aioresponses() as m:
        yield m

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def tg_token():
    TEST_FAKE_TOKEN = "12345:TEST_FAKE_TOKEN"
    yield TEST_FAKE_TOKEN

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def client_tgbot(tg_token):
    client = ClientTgBot(tg_token)
    yield client
```

Our test case:

```
# tests/test_client_tgbot_unit.py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_sendMessage(tg_token, client_tgbot, mock_aioresponse):
    JSON_RESPONSE_WRONG_MARKDOWN = {'ok': False, 'error_code': 400, 'description': "Bad Request: can't parse entities: Can't find end of the entity starting at byte offset 3"}
    mock_aioresponse.post(f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{tg_token}/sendMessage", payload=JSON_RESPONSE_WRONG_MARKDOWN)

    response = await client_tgbot.sendMessage(435627225, "bot_sent")

    assert response.status == 400
    assert await response.json() == JSON_RESPONSE_WRONG_MARKDOWN
```

Install some libs:

```
pip3 install aiohttp aioresponses pytest pytest-asyncio
```

And run your tests:

```
python3 -m pytest -s . -vv
```

As you see, we've mocked the whole url `https://api.telegram.org/bot12345:TEST_FAKE_TOKEN/sendMessage` without sending POST request to the real host. Also we don't have any fake session.